# How to compile a whole R source packages with Clang -Wno-nullability-completeness option in OSX 10.15

Tags: c++, r, macos, llvm-clang

Based on several postings in stackoverflow, in OSX 10.15, I can suppress `warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]` from `conftest.c`  by  `clang -Wno-nullability-completeness -o conftest -g -O2 -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  conftest.c` or `gcc -Wno-nullability-completeness conftest.c`. But how can I implement this for compiling a whole R pacakge from the source ?  I added `-Wno-nullability-completeness` in  R Makevers like this :

```
CC=clang -Wno-nullability-completeness
CXX=clang++ -Wno-nullability-completeness
CFLAGS=-Wno-nullability-completeness -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS=-Wno-nullability-completeness -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L$(LLVM_LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LLVM_LOC)/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I$(LLVM_LOC)/include
```

but it did not work.   Any suggestions or pointers will be seriously appreciated.

My system;

```
sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.15.2
BuildVersion:   19C57

gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_2/libexec/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin19/9.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19
Configured with: ../configure --build=x86_64-apple-darwin19 --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_2 --libdir=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/9.2.0_2/lib/gcc/9 --disable-nls --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran --program-suffix=-9 --with-gmp=/usr/local/opt/gmp --with-mpfr=/usr/local/opt/mpfr --with-mpc=/usr/local/opt/libmpc --with-isl=/usr/local/opt/isl --with-system-zlib --with-pkgversion='Homebrew GCC 9.2.0_2' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues --disable-multilib --with-native-system-header-dir=/usr/include --with-sysroot=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk
Thread model: posix
gcc version 9.2.0 (Homebrew GCC 9.2.0_2)

clang -v
clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.2.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin

brew info R
R: stable 3.6.2 (bottled)
Software environment for statistical computing
https://www.r-project.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/R/3.6.2 (2,123 files, 58.5MB)
  Poured from bottle on 2019-12-14 at 09:37:12
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/r.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: gcc ✔, gettext ✔, jpeg ✔, libpng ✔, openblas ✔, pcre ✔, readline ✔, xz ✔
```

Flags:

```
CPATH=/usr/local/include
LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/llvm/include
SDKROOT=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX10.15.sdk
```

**Edit 1**

From a suggestion by Ralf Stubner,  I looked at an installer output generated by `install.package("e1071", keep_outputs=T)` ;

```
All my packages loaded Tue Dec 31 16:23:24 2019* installing *source* package ‘e1071’ ...
** package ‘e1071’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for C++ compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C++ compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether clang++ -std=gnu++11 accepts -g... yes
** libs
clang -I"/usr/local/Cellar/r/3.6.2/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG   -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/include  **-fPIC  -g -O2**  -c Rsvm.c -o Rsvm.o
In file included from Rsvm.c:2:
/usr/local/include/stdio.h:67:13: warning: pointer is missing a nullability type specifier (_Nonnull, _Nullable, or _Null_unspecified) [-Wnullability-completeness]
extern FILE *__stdinp ........;
```

and I realized that CXXFLAGs in my Makevars may not be read by clang at all.  A following is my current Makevars;

```
LLVM_LOC = /usr/local/opt/llvm
CC=clang
CXX=clang++
CXX11=clang++

CFLAGS = -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-nonnull -std=gnu99 -mtune=native
CXXFLAGS = -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-nonnull -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native
CXX11FLAGS = -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-nonnull -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native

LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L$(LLVM_LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LLVM_LOC)/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I$(LLVM_LOC)/include
```

Comment: You might have to add this flag also for `CXX98`, `CXX11`, `CXX14` and `CXX17`.

Comment: @RalfStubner, could you show me an example of a correct FLAG setting ? CXX14, for example, CXX14=clang++ -std=c++14, and CXX14FLAGs=-Wno-nullability-completeness -g -O3 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++14 -mtune=native ?  Thanks.

Comment: Your line for `CXXFLAGS` looks correct. Duplicate that for `CXX11FLAGS` etc. If that doesn’t work, please post the generated compile command that produces the warning.

Comment: @RalfStubner,  I tired with the modified Makevars with all CXX flags as you suggested but did not work at all.  Reinstallation of R, using Apple's llvm instead of brew's llvm, and using 10.14's libs did not work either.  I use "install.package" from R and  am not sure the actual compile commands are but I believe, they are "./ configure && make && make install"  I down loaded and tried to compile a few R packages from their sources but ./configure did not generate make files although with an exit code =0. At this point,  I feel that I need to do a nuclear option, clean install OSX 10.15

Comment: When you use `install.packages` on a R package that needs compilation, the actual compile commands are part of the generated output. These lines should start with `clang` or `clang++`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured this out. Thanks to the help from RalfStubner.  I realized that I was not putting Makevars in the right location. A default location of Makevars should be ~/.R/Makevars.  Now, CXXFLAGS in the Makevars is read and  `-Wno-nonnull` is applied.  My latest Makevars is as follows;

```
LLVM_LOC = /usr/local/opt/llvm
CC=$(LLVM_LOC)/bin/clang -fopenmp
CXX=$(LLVM_LOC)/bin/clang++ -fopenmp

CC=clang
CXX=clang++
CXX11=clang++

CFLAGS = -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -pedantic -Wno-nonnull -std=gnu99 -mtune=native -pipe
CXXFLAGS = -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-nonnull -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native
CXX11FLAGS = -g -O3 -Wall -pipe -Wno-nonnull -pedantic -std=c++11 -mtune=native

LDFLAGS=-L/usr/local/opt/gettext/lib -L$(LLVM_LOC)/lib -Wl,-rpath,$(LLVM_LOC)/lib
CPPFLAGS=-I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I$(LLVM_LOC)/include
```